# asynchronously add epic to middleware in redux-observable

Tags: javascript, redux, action, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm trying to evaluate redux-observable.  Just looking through the doc and I'm trying to get the async epic loading thing going.  I created a fork of the jsbin from the docs which basically attempts to add the async usage of the BehaviorSubject stuff.

http://jsbin.com/bazoqemiqu/edit?html,js,output

In that 'PING PONG' example, I added an 'OTHER' action and then use BehaviorSubject.next (as described in the docs) to add that epic.  However, when I run the example, what happens is that the PING action is fired, followed by an endless stream of 'OTHER' actions, but never the PONG action.  To see this, I added the reduxLogger.  View it in the dev tools console as the jsbin console doesn't render it correctly.

My question is what am I doing wrong?  Why does the PONG action never get dispatched?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Your `otherEpic` is an infinite "loop" (over time)

```js
const otherEpic$ = action$ => 
  action$
    .delay(1000)
    .mapTo({ type: OTHER });
```

This epic has the behavior "when *any* action at all is received, wait 1000ms and then emit another action of type `OTHER`". And since the actions your Epics emit go through the normal `store.dispatch` cycle like any other action, that means after the first `PING` is received, it will emit an `OTHER` after 1000ms, which will then be recursively received by the same epic again, wait another 1000ms and emit *another* `OTHER`, repeat forever.

I'm not sure if this was known, but wanted to point it out.

#### You `next()` into the BehaviorSubject of `epic$` before your rootEpic has started running/been subscribed to it.

BehaviorSubjects will keep the *last* value emitted and provide that immediately when someone subscribes. Since your rootEpic has not yet been called and subscribed to the by the middleware, you're replacing the **initial** value, so only the `otherEpic` is emitted and ran through the `epic$.mergeMap` stuff.

In a real application with async/bundle splitting, when you would call `epic$.next(newEpic)` should *always* be after the middleware has subscribed to your rootEpic and received the initial epic you provided to your `BehaviorSubject`.

Here's a demo of that working: http://jsbin.com/zaniviz/edit?js,output

```js
const epic$ = new BehaviorSubject(combineEpics(epic1, epic2, ...etc));
const rootEpic = (action$, store) =>
  epic$.mergeMap(epic => {console.log(epic)
    return epic(action$, store)
  });

const otherEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(PONG)
    .delay(1000)
    .mapTo({ type: OTHER });

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic);
const store = createStore(rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(loggerMiddleware, epicMiddleware)
);

// any time AFTER the epicMiddleware
// has received the rootEpic
epic$.next(otherEpic);
```

The documentation says "sometime later" in the example, which I now see isn't clear enough. I'll try and clarify this further.

---

You may also find [this other question on async loading of Epics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202074/is-it-an-efficient-practice-to-add-new-epics-lazily-inside-react-router-onenter/40210421) useful if you're using react-router with Webpack's `require.enquire()` splitting.

Let me know if I can clarify any of these further

Comment: How to combine dynamically with new version ```Uncaught TypeError: Providing your root Epic to `createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic)` is no longer supported, instead use `epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic)` ```